# Double swing door

Tags: doors, hinges, swing

I have a door in a restaurant that swings into the kitchen and out into the dining room at the top is hitting the wall as it closes. Originally I had two hinges on the top and one hinge on the bottom because the door is kind of heavy. Just now I added another double swing hinge to the metals trying to support some more weight but it's still hitting the top what do I do

Comment: Add an image or two to your post. Typically a door hinge has at least one screw that goes through the superficial door frame and into the structural framing behind it.

Comment: Does a restaurant door necessarily qualify as "home improvement?"

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the rest of the door fit, either the bottom hinge needs to be closer to the jamb, or the top hinges need to be further away from the jamb. Or maybe both in extreme cases.